# Mongo if inside $match and $or

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've been stuck with this for a quite while.
I want to filter specials.name field based on two inputs from my form - select and input field. The problem is, whatever I tried, it always chooses on of it.
Is there any way to put if, else block inside $or to make it work?

This is the last thing that I tried, and now it works always on searchInput, which is input field, it does not react on changes in select menu.

```html
{
 $match: { 
  $or: [ 
   { 'specials.name':{$in :[searchSpecials, searchInput]}}, 
  ] 
 }
}
```

```html
const searchSpecials = req.body.searchSpecials
const searchInput = req.body.search
```

Comment: Are req.body.searchSpecials and req.body.search strings or arrays?

Comment: If they are strings it is working as expected, I guess at least one of them is not a string...

Comment: No, both of them are strings

Comment: Please share some sample data

Comment: Hi, can you add some example documents and expected output?

Comment: Hi, I solved it, thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two inputs are strings, this works as expected:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {"specials.name": {$in: ["Malinda", "Joseph"]}}
  }
])
```

and returns:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "specials": {
      "name": "Malinda"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "specials": {
      "name": "Joseph"
    }
  }
]
```

As you can see [here, on the playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OHvAQDjsaQg).
No need for the `$or`, since the `$in` will return all documents that have `specials.name` which is included in the list of options.